# writing heap summary to file in valgrind

Tags: memory, valgrind

I am using valgrind's memcheck to monitor my program. 
The heap summary generated is big in size to atleast copy.

How can I copy the heap summary stuff into a file in Valgrind.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valgrind has multiple ways to redirect its output.

1. to a file
   valgrind --log-file=valgrind.out --leak-check=full yourapp
2. to any file descriptor.
   valgrind --log-fd=123 --leak-check=full yourapp 123>valgrind.out
3. to an ipaddr/port nr
   valgrind --log-socket=

You can also redirect valgrind output to a ipaddr/port nr using
--log-socket=ipaddr:port (you must then start valgrind-listener on this port).